# Tools for refactoring c++ code

Tags: projectile, c++, helm-projectile, refactoring

What tools do you use to refactor c++ code? For example, how do you rename a variable or function that is spread across files?

---

If the problem isn't language specific, there are text-based tools that can aid this process. For example `projectile-replace` and replacing words would be easy. But this can be a pain if there are functions that are named similarly, for example

1. `void foo();`
2. `void fooFighter();`
3. `void Fighterfoo();`

If I want to rename `foo` to something like `foo1`, the `projectile-replace` would match with instances of the other functions and it's mildly time-consuming.